# How to open keyboard on focus() event of textbox in mobile chrome browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-events

Trying to focus on a simple input text when the page loads with jQuery events, my target is to focus and open the keyboard on mobile browsers but it's not working.

My code looks so simple as:

```
$('#txtNumber').focus();
$('#txtNumber').trigger('click');
```

I'm not sure what I am missing here to open the keyboard on the browser when focusing on the text input box.

Comment: It's a usability issue that the keyboard should not be allowed to be triggered except by user input

Comment: Have you tried $(textFiled).trigger("focus"); ?

Comment: @JeffB, I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: @VNB Ah, I think that worked for a minute in the past. But Mehdi is correct, websites are generally not allowed to open a keyboard. You need to have a native app to do that.